# Suggestions on improving an elevated-bed project?

Tags: design

I have my bed in a corner of the room and I want to elevate it.
I don't like any of the IKEA solutions and the like because I want the corner of the bed that is away from the walls to be free.
So I've made my own project [image: Elevated bed]

I've made it with this free android app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jquinn.qubism.android
You can get the project and explore it in more detail here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mxg4r9gjd414zaj/5ae1753a-7a34-4761-a357-c30bf3196f54.json?dl=0

The red wall cannot bear any weight, but he other wall is concrete.
I would like to avoid turning the bed (so that the pillar can be fastened to the bearing wall) because this would take away the space for a desk.
My plan is to just make the pillar fit exactly the height of the room so that it locks in (split it in two pieces, a main tall one and a smaller top that I can slide in), basically leaving no room for the pillar to tip.
I am counting on this being able to sustain any weight and pulling I might stress on the far end of the crossbeam, since the ceiling is also concrete.
I would also run a cable from the joint between the pillar and the  crossbeam toward the concrete wall, to put some tension and fasten everything together in that direction.
I am planning to use 15x15cm massive wood for pillar and crossbeam.

This is my very first own wood project
- Do you seen any flaws in the plan?
- Do you have improvements?
If you think it can work
- What kind of joint would you make between the pillar and crossbeam? I simply plan to cut out 5cm out of each and insert them into each other, the the bolt for the cable would fasten them together but would not need to bear any weight.

Comment: How are you planning to get in and out of bed?  Is there a ladder which is not shown in your plans?  If so, permanently mount it to the bed corner furthest from all of the walls and reinforce it's floor-to-bed length posts to bear some weight from that cantilevered corner.  As currently designed, anyone sitting on that corner of the bed will be putting a tremendous wrenching torsion on the whole structure.

Comment: Climbing is easy for me, so that's spot on, I am exactly asking if a structure like this can hold safely without reinforcing that corner with something that occupies the corner top to bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This design is NOT ready for prime time!

- Wedging the main column from the floor to ceiling is not adequate.  Every structure has movement and changes size a bit as the seasons change.  What is a tight fit now, may not be in six months or a year.  The column should be physically anchored to the floor and ceiling with mechanical fasteners.  The floor connection can be a standard column base available from big box stores, but it must be connected with bolts or tapcons (assuming a concrete floor).  IF it is a wood frame floor you may need to open the floor deck up and reinforce the wood framing. You do not mention the construction for the ceiling, but the column must anchor to a securely as to the floor.  The connections must also resist twist to prevent the column from rotating along its vertical axis.
- The connect between the horizontal beam and column must be secured with bolts to prevent the beam from pulling out away column.
- The beam and the diagonal brace must be of adequate size to support the loads and rotational force the bed load will place on the composite support structure.  I would actually recommend talking to a structural engineer about the sizes. The fact that the beam cantilevers beyond the diagonal support creates additional structural stress on the beam member.
- The bed resting on the beam at the foot of the bed will also apply a twisting load on the beam's horizontal axis and the beam must be have enough width to resist that twist.
- One way to resist the twist in the beam and rotation of the column would be to put a framing member from the concrete wall to the outside corner of the beam.  A similar framing member along the face of the red wall would help stabilize the column.  In other words, create a bed support frame on all four sides to support the bed.
- Secure the manufactured bed on the beams at the head and foot with secure fasteners.  The connections of the head and foot of the bed to the mattress support frame may not be adequate to insure it stays on the narrow ledges in the structural beams you are designing.
- Keep in mind getting in  and out of the bed will place lots of horizontal forces on the structure at the level of the bed  itself, both from getting in and out of it and moving around on top of it.  When a bed is on the floor these are resisted close to bed frame itself.  In this design the forces travel longer which amplify the loads like a lever does. Everything must be stronger and securely fastened.

There are other possible solutions for your project.  This may be the best approach for you situation, but I would encourage you to consider others before proceeding as well.